# MySql set id_auto-increment keep skipping number after insert fail

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I'm working on a project creating a REST Api using Spring Boot and MySQL.

I have a table of users:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    user_password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    phone_number CHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)    
);
```

Here is my Postmapping method using Spring boot:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        boolean success = userService.createUser(user);
        if (success) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("User created successfully!");
        }
        else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
        }
    }
}
```

It works very well until I realized if I try to insert fail, the user_id will skip that number.

For example, the first time I insert successfully, the user_id will start from 1.

The second time I insert fail

The third time inserts successfully, then the user_id will be 3.

Does anyone have any idea to fix it?

Comment: *Does anyone have any idea to fix it?* You shouldn't fix this - this is a norma. if you need in adjacent enumeration then create separate coluymn for this purposes and assing it programmatically. `AUTO_INCREMENT` guarantees that next value will be above previous one, but it does not (and should not) provide values adjacency.

Answer (score 0):

Auto increment doesn't care, if you delete some rows - everytime you insert a row or insert fails, the value is incremented.

if the INSERT fails. That is, it increments by 1 each time, but doesn't undo an increment if the INSERT fails.

If you want a numbering without gaps, don't use auto-increment and do it by yourself. You could use something like this to achive this for inserting.